# implementing the action bar in the android

Tags: android, eclipse, implementation, android-actionbar

[image: gmail app in android]

I want to implement an action bar for my own android app like the one on the bottom  on the picture.
I searched a lot, But a lot of errors appears.

I tried some libraries for some help like : Greendroid and ActionBarSherlock but none of them work, Or I couldn't use them perfectly! ..

I'm really in need for that action bar in my app.

I will be grateful if someone could help me with some Samples or codes or explain it to me.

Thanks a lot :) ..

Comment: "But a lot of errors appears." is there any error in using uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" ?

Comment: NO not in that line, another for "WindowsTitleBackground" on the style.xml file! .. I read about splitactionbarwhenNarrow but I couldn't apply it because the errors :(

Comment: it says that WindowsTitleBackground is not a resource for android ..
that's when I use GreenDroid Library ! ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a SplitActionBar. Your application suppost to be running on Android 4.0 (API level 14) or higher

the fix is to always have an item in the top bar that prevents the bottom content from ever fitting in there, thus forcing everything into the bottom bar. Look at this sample project from another user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
<manifest package="com.commonsware.android.actionbarbc"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
               android:icon="@drawable/cw"
               android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:name=".InflationDemo"
              android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
            android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="true"
                    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
</manifest>
```

He used this code for his activity:

```
private void setupActionBar() {
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(this)
    .inflate(R.layout.conversation_list_actionbar, null);
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(v,
        new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT));

mUnreadConvCount = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.unread_conv_count);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{me.adly.action/me.adly.action.InflationDemo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.adly.action.InflationDemo

it gives me that error in the log cat tracer!? so what's the problem?

Comment: The InflationDemo activity was not found in your project. Check your manifest and activity names or you intent objects.

Comment: That's worked :), 

that's what appeared for me ! : http://postimage.org/image/tsyneui1j/

can you provide me with a link for the source code of the snippet  above?

Comment: Here's the snippet link that i found from another user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465258/how-can-i-force-the-action-bar-to-be-at-the-bottom-in-ics If my answer helped please accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at something called SplitActionBar.

The documentation for this is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

From reading briefly about it, it only applies to "Narrow" screens and you declare that you want to use the split action bar by adding `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` into the  or  element in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

You may be able to force it to appear all the time but I don't know as I haven't used it before.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I read about it at first, But I couldn't find any sample code to apply perfectly, can you help me on that?

Comment: I made it sucessfully, but there is a thing about what you said, when I add 5 elements in the menu, the action bar shows only 3 elements and doesn't make like the pic above ? so what do you think the problem? 
i put what you said about : splitactionbarwhennarow, but still not working ..???