# Gmail-like view in ICS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm having trouble with layouts and would like to create a view similar to the ICS gmail view where there are 4 sections.  The first is the title bar, second is the body, the 3rd is the summary of # of messages, and 4th is a menu bar that's always present.  I would also like the same behaviour where you can swipe left and right to get the next message.  Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do such a thing?  Sorry for my newbie-ness as I'm learning, hope this isn't a stupid question...

[image: Screenshot of view explained above]

Answer (score 2):

hope my answer helps you. Although what you have asked is very broad and since you haven't tried any code. I would ask you to do so first. Understand the mechanism of relative and linear layouts. So here are some guidelines.

The #1. you have represented can be accomplished with implementing [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html) (from android developers blog) its a really best way I found useful or the awesome opensource [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) read through their [documentation](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html) for a better understanding.

The #2. you have mentioned can be made with `viewPager`a good example to use it can be found [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-horizontal-view-paging/)

The #3rd i suppose must be a layout inflated showing stats. (sorry i do not own a ICS powered android phone)

and for #4. you can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465258/how-can-i-force-the-action-bar-to-be-at-the-bottom-in-ics) and also [this](http://android-ed.blogspot.in/2011/12/using-actionbar-at-bottom-of-screen.html)

**And before all that. Please code and show us what you have got and we could show you better ways for it, or if you are too good we would appreciate you.**