# How to display both normal and split ActionBar?

Tags: android, gmail, android-actionbar

I have more then a few ActionBar items, and I am using splitActionBarWhenNarrow option. Latest Gmail app also uses it. But it also have a custom item on upper right that shows the current number of unread emails. When I use splitActionBar it sends all my action items to the bottom. How can I send some of them to bottom and force some of them to be in the upper side.

[image: see upper right corner]

Comment: I have heard that it is currently not possible although don't remember the reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When the ActionBar is splitted (using `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"`), all menu items automatically go to the bottom bar but custom view can still be put in the top.

```
View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null);
getActionBar().setCustomView(customView);
```

Comment: Woooow that is fantastic. I havent used any custom view for action bar but I definitely want to use it. But we cannot put the custom view to the bottom right?

Comment: I'm nearly sure you can't put a custom view on the bottom..  but here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816041/android-actionbar-push-custom-view-to-bottom-of-screen is a recent similar question, and somehow the author found a way to make sort of a custom view from a menu item. I tested it, it works for me.