# Use actionbar in top and bottom of screen at same time

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-actionbar-compat

I'm making an example that have a actionbar on top & bottom of screen. Menu item can place in both of actionbar.

Now I'm using [appcompat](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) to create actionbar.

I've tried [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571754/android-split-action-bar-with-action-items-on-the-top-and-bottom). But the menu item is only show on split actionbar not top actionbar.

Here is the result that I expected:

[image]

How can I do that, any suggestion are good for me.

Comment: have you tried this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077690/how-to-display-both-normal-and-split-actionbar

Comment: The bottom controls should be part of the layout. Use a `RelativeLayout` with match_parent on width and height and put the map control on the bottom of the RelativeLayout as the last item that gets drawn.

Comment: @smitalm I've just tried, but I don't know the reason why Top actionbar doesn't show up

Comment: @gunar thanks for idea, I'll try to create 2 custom View when no choice

Comment: @Dolphin: you need only a custom view for bottom view. The top one can be put in the actionbar.

Comment: @gunar I've try custom both of actionbar & just bottom actionbar. Your solution are the best. Thanks for suggestion :)