# Is it possible to customize items in split action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menu-items, splitactionbar

I'm working with split action bar for my project, i would like to know is it possible to customize the items position in split action bar (i.e) i want some of the menu items in top of the action bar and some of them bottom of the action bar dynamically as my wish is it possible ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use normal actions on the top and split ActionBar at the same time. There is a trick you can use that is described below:

[How to display both normal and split ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077690/how-to-display-both-normal-and-split-actionbar)

But it is an old question and `ActionBar` is deprecated. You can now use multiple `Toolbar` objects instead of `ActionBar`. That way you can keep one of them at the bottom and add whatever actions you want to it.