# How can I move the action bar navigation tabs to the bottom?

Tags: android-actionbar, android

Let me preface this by saying I know this goes against the [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).

I want to be able to take the built-in navigation tabs for the action bar and move them to the bottom of the screen. I looked through the [Javadocs for `ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) and didn't see any built-in functionality (rightfully so). Does anyone know of some way, perhaps through overriding styles or themes, to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465258/how-can-i-force-the-action-bar-to-be-at-the-bottom-in-ics

Comment: I don't think there is anything in styles/themes that will accomplish this. Even the above post will still have the tabs on top; splitting the action bar just means you want the system to show additional actions on the bottom instead of cramming them all into the overflow menu. You will likely have to implement this on your own. You could also use the older TabHost and TabWidget classes; that's how I've done it in the past (search google for it, there are some examples out there).

Comment: @Karakuri That's about what I figured. Thanks for your response.