# ActionBarSherlock in the bottom of screen

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have searched a lot how to position ActionBarSherlock to the bottom of the screen and Thanks God it works using this code

```
<activity
   android:name=".MyActivity"
   android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
</activity>
```

but with a small problem that the header is still there and I want to remove it also, so can any one please help me remove the header of ActionBarSherlock

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465258

Comment: sorry Nachi but this doesn't help as it is for ICS devices, but I'm using ActionBarSherlock to be able to use action bar for earlier devices and I want to remove the title in this library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

splitActionBarWhenNarrow means that it will be split, not moved anywhere and only when narrow. Thus if you are in portrait or wide screen the menu options will always appear at the top. You cannot force ActionBar to be drawn at the bottom. Instead you might want to disable ActionBar completely and putting your own custom view at the bottom with ImageButtons with actionButtonStyle

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style> 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttons_holder"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/acion_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_add"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_prev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_prev"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_next"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But I'm using ActionBarSherlock to be ablt to make Action Bar in earlier devices like 2.3.3

Comment: It is not possible to put ActionBar to the bottom. You can use a layout that looks alike instead.

Comment: @DoctororDrive : I have seen the action bar on the bottom of the screen in the "demo app" -"Split action Item"

Comment: @kAnNaN it wasn't at the bottom. It was at the top and the menu items at the bottom. That's why it is called "split". And it will not remain split on tablets or in landscape mode.