# ActionBar at bottom with no TitleBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-actionbar

In my app I have an ActionBar and have set `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in the manifest so on phones the it appears at the bottom.

I also set the following in code:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

When I run the application in the emulator, I see the actionbar at the bottom but a black empty space where the icon and title should be if I don't disable them.

Can this be removed?

Its like this:

[image]

I started with left image before adding the code above and rather than seeing the centre image I see it as the right-hand image. I am not using the tabs in the images.... does this matter? Just using image for explanation!

Comment: You can read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465258/how-can-i-force-the-action-bar-to-be-at-the-bottom-in-ics

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I can and have read that, but I don't see a solution in that question? Are you able to actually point it out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8465258/420015

Comment: @aneal I disagree that this is a duplicate. I already have the ActionBar at the bottom, I just want to remove the TitleBar

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

inside  your AndroidManifest.xml?