# Create 2 action bars, one on the bottom and another on the top

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37599516/Untitled.png]

I am a beginner in android and I want to create a simple app with a great UI like the Quizlet App in the picture above.  The question is how to create 2 separate action bars, one on the top and another on the bottom like that.

Comment: have a look at this post. There is loads of information on your topic!!  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8465258/2074990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app manifest, for this activity, set

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

Refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html for all the details.

Please be aware that when in landscape mode, the split action bar will not appear, the buttons will show in the single action bar at the top and may get moved into overflow if insufficient room.