# How to place android "actionbar tab" at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I want to create bottom `ActionBar Tab`, not `SplitActionBarWhenNarrow`. So can I place the android `ActionBarTab` at the bottom of the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by setting a custom action bar view, and set layout params in the setupActionBar() like so,

```
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
        ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(v,
        new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT));
```

More info here as this is a repeat question, [How can I force the Action Bar to be at the bottom in ICS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465258/how-can-i-force-the-action-bar-to-be-at-the-bottom-in-ics)