# Action bar show only at bottom in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm new to android please suggest me.................

I was working in Full page webview in that i need to hide top action bar and show bottom action bar. I tried in many ways to do this task but there are lot conflict between top bar and bottom bar  when i make hide top action bar at the same time bottom bar also hiding i'm searching for the solution. Can you please provide me suggest to do in this task.

```
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/sample"
    android:label="@string/app_name"  >


    <activity
        android:name="controller.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="controller.TestingActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:label="@string/title_student_registration" >
                <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
               android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
    </activity> 

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465258/how-can-i-force-the-action-bar-to-be-at-the-bottom-in-ics

Comment: Finally it does't work in this scenario. We can't able to make action bar at the bottom instead of this we can able to make new layout at bottom like footer. For the menu items make popup window